# touchesEnd does not get called bit touchesBegin and touchesMoved does get called

Tags: ios

I'm trying to do a drag in ios.  If the drag movement was a short distance, I was going to count the drag as a click event, by comparing the start x,y (from touchesBegan) to the x,y in touchesEnd.
It seems like touchesEnd never gets called.  I put a break point to verify it and the break point never went off.

```
code:
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSUInteger touchCount = [touches count];
    NSUInteger tapCount = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];

    [ self UpdateDrag];

   }

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSUInteger touchCount = [touches count];
    NSUInteger tapCount = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];

    }


- (void) touchesEnd:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   // this methes never gets called 
    NSUInteger touchCount = [touches count];
    NSUInteger tapCount = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];


    if (mDisplay==nil)
    {
        mDisplay = [[cDisplayYesOrNo_iPhone alloc]
                    initWithNibName:@"cDisplayYesOrNo_iPhone"
                    bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
    [ mDisplay SetUp];
    [self presentModalViewController: mDisplay animated:NO];


}
```

Answer (score 6):

Is `- (void)touchesEnded:` not `- (void)touchesEnd:`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesEnded:withEvent:

Answer (score 4):

You need to edit `touchesEnd` to `touchesEnded`.

Also, for completeness, you need to consider whether you also need to respond to `touchesCancelled` which is called instead of `touchesEnded` in some circumstances.